# Transforming file URLs in Phonegap

Tags: cordova, file-upload, local-storage

I have a PhoneGap app on iOS that takes photos and moves them to a directory called "images". I can successfully create the "images" directory (located in the app's "Documents" directory), and I can successfully move the file into that directory. However, I also need to update the local SQLite database with this file URL so that the image shows up in a regular `img` HTML element, and this is where I am stuck.

So my question is, how can I transform a `dirname + "/" + newFilename` into a `file:///` URL?

```
var dirname = 'images';
app.fs.root.getDirectory(dirname, {
    create:true,
    exclusive:false
}, function(directoryEntry) {
    var newFilename = self.id() + '.jpg';
    originalFileEntry.moveTo(directoryEntry, newFilename, function(){
        // Success! Now I want to get the "file:///" URL
    }, function(){
        failure('An error occurred when moving the newly taken photo to the data directory.');
    });
}, function(err){
    failure('An error occurred when creating a directory into which the animal photo should be saved.');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To get file's absolute path you can use

```
app.fs.root.fullPath + "/" + dirname + "/" + newFilename
```